# file contents modified on end of execution

Tags: c, file-io

I am developing a utility which scans multiple text files, extracts relevant text and dumps it into another text file.

```
int main()
{
    // file I/O code
    node *temp1;
   char script[255],segName[255],ch;
   char *dev;
   FILE *fp;
   int i=0;
   void removeSpace();

   dev=getenv("DEVSET");
   devset = atoi(dev);
   //clearing the file before starting
   fp=fopen("output.txt","w");
   fclose(fp);

   memset(script,'\0',sizeof(script));
   strcpy(script,"main"); // start with main
   head=createNode(script); // head is a global node*
   head->prev=NULL;
   head->next=NULL;
   temp1 = head;

   while(temp1 !=NULL)
   {


       read(temp1, script);// reads the text file corresponding to temp1 and   returns relevant data

       memset(segName,'\0',sizeof(segName));
       if (strcmp((temp1->name),"main"))
       {
           //if not main, start on a new line
           segName[0]='\n';
       }


       if (strcmp(script,"EOF")== 0 || strcmp(script,"")== 0 )
       {
           // end of file or Call not found
           temp1 = pop(head);

       }
       else
       {
           if (strcmp(script,"exit_flow") == 0)
           {

               fp=fopen("output.txt","a");

               fprintf(fp,"//FNF");
               fclose(fp);

               temp1=pop(head);

           }
           else
           {
              //Call found

              for(i=0;i<script_index;i++) // script index is a global int
              {
                  strcat(segName,"-"); // no of dashes indicate depth of the call
              }

              strcat(segName,"<");
              i=strlen(segName);
              segName[i]=call_type;
              strcat(segName,">");
              strcat(segName,(script));

              fp=fopen("output.txt","a");
              fprintf(fp,segName);
              fclose(fp);
              script_index++;
              temp1=createNode(script);
              push(head,temp1);
           }
       }
   }// end of while

   // Adjustment to remove extra spaces from the file
   removeSpace();
   fclose(fp);
    if(!devset)
        printf("\nExecution complete");

    printf("\nResult dumped to \"output.txt\"");

    printf("\nOpen the output file? ");
    fflush(stdin);

    ch=getchar();
    if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        system("notepad output.txt");// Text file displayed has correct data here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mentioned above is a part main().

How much ever it may seem improbable, the contents of the file are modified after execution of the 'system' statement.
A string(not exactly random) gets appended to the text file, although I have closed the file prior to the execution of 'system'.

> Environment - windows
>
> IDE- Code::Blocks
>
> Compiler - MinGW

Is this because I haven't flushed some buffer?

Comment: There's a log of missing code, and also doing `fflush` on `stdin` is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: The posted code has multiple issues, it's not by chance the real code because it would never compile, for instance where is `fp` declared? why do you `fclose()` it, if it has not been `fopen()`ed? and `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Does the "string (not exactly random)" give you a clue?

Comment: This doesn't compile. `ch` is not defined.

Comment: @jongware
yes, but as you can see in the snippet
I have closed the file.
then displayed it using 'system', where the data is correct.
After the execution, when I open the file the extra string is appended

Comment: @PrateekKhankhoje , As it currently stands, a lot of information is missing. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code that you excluded as *irrelevant". Post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Prateek: no, we can not see what's going on in the snippet you have posted, becaue it is incomplete and (as far as any of the rest of us can see) meaningless.

Comment: @iharob 
My mistake,
the code mentioned in the question is a partial snippet(which I felt relevant, in order to emphasize on the fac that after fclose() when 'system' executes, the text is correct, but changes later on).
I have fopen()ed the FILE* fp.

Comment: And what clue *does* that not-exactly-random-string give you? Is it something like "C:\Documents>Program terminated", or "140: error: 'ch' was not declared in this scope", or .. wait, why do I need to guess?

Comment: Prateek: the partial snipped you have posted is not relevant.  Whatever your problem is, it's in the code you're not showing us.  We can't answer your question based on the snippet you've shown us.

Comment: @SteveSummit 
I have updated the code in question details

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's still not complete.  We can't see where `removeSpace` is called. `removeSpace` closes a `fp` which is not declared.  I haven't unraveled your program's control flow, but since I don't know when `removeSpace` is called, and since I do see a file getting opened in append more to add more text to it, I'm not surprised to hear you report that more text is getting added to a file some time later.

Comment: @SteveSummit
removeSpace is added just to make the text file content more readable.
you can ignore the call and declaration.
I encountered the same issue when I commented removeSpace

Comment: See, this is why people keep asking you to post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.  Reading quickly, and based on the indentation, I thought that the code you're asking about -- the `system(notepad)` call -- was _in a function called removeSpace_. It's impossible to help you when you post such a misleading example.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete, but it's likely that your program is (a) opening a file for writing, (b) writing some data to it, (c) invoking notepad to let the user view the file, and (d) exiting.

However: When your program exits, any unwritten data is flushed and any open files are closed.  It's likely that it's this final implicit flush/close that is appending the extra data you're asking about.

Try calling `fflush(outputfile)` or `fclose(outputfile)` before calling `system`.

Comment: I have done a fclose() before calling 'system'
I tried fflush(fp) before the fclose(), but it didn't fix the issue.

note: I have updated the code for your reference

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what's going on, but here is a second answer.  Please follow these steps.

1. Delete *every* call to `fopen`, `fflush`, and `fclose` in your
   program.  Every one.
2. Add a single call to `fopen` at the very top of your program, to open `output.txt` for writing.  Do not use append (`'a'`) mode.
3. Add a single call to `fclose` towards the end of your program, right before you call `system` to open notepad.

This should make your program behave more sensibly (and it will also be easier to follow).

Comment: Side comment: One trick I use in cases like this, to make _sure_ I've found every call to fopen, fflush, and fclose, is to delete the declaration `FILE *fp`, and create a new declaration `FILE *new_output_fp`, and use `new_output_fp` in my new set of I/O calls.  That way, if there's one of the old `fclose(fp)` calls hiding somewhere that I missed, the compiler will warn me about it, because now `fp` is undefined.